# CakePHP : Hide CRUD action (conditional)

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I would like to hide a CRUD `action` depending on the value of a variable( `if $sType->payment` is `true` then hide it otherwise show it). This is how I am trying to do it without any success.

```
<?php (!$sType->payment ? $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $sType->id]) : '') ?>
```

What am I missing? I can see with `debug()` that `$sType->payment` contains the expected value.

Comment: you are missing the  `echo`  statement

Comment: @tphobe9312 if I add the `echo $this->Html->link.....` I receive this error : syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: `<?php echo (!$sType->payment...` do like this

Comment: Or `<?php if (!$sType->payment) echo ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `=`  Replace

`<?php (!$sType->payment ? $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $sType->id]) : '') ?>`

To

`<?= (!$sType->payment ? $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $sType->id]) : '') ?>`